# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).collision is not a function

Tags: jquery

How can I add a point to the score after the black and green divs is in collision? After you move the black div with the up, down, left, right and it intersects the green div I would like to add a point to the score in the `#score` div. I use collision function and it gives me the error in the title.

The code can be rewritten if you have other suggestions. I will appreciate any help.

```js
var pane = $('#pane'),
    box = $('#box'),
    boxGreen=$('#box-green'),
    w = pane.width() - box.width(),
    d = {},
    x = 3;

function newv(v,a,b) {
    var n = parseInt(v, 10) - (d[a] ? x : 0) + (d[b] ? x : 0);
    return n < 0 ? 0 : n > w ? w : n;
}

$(window).keydown(function(e) { d[e.which] = true; });
$(window).keyup(function(e) { d[e.which] = false; });

setInterval(function() {
    box.css({
        left: function(i,v) { return newv(v, 37, 39); },
        top: function(i,v) { return newv(v, 38, 40); }
    });
}, 20);

var randomNumberAppearGreenBox=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);

// make position sensitive to size and document's width
var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 20).toFixed();
var posx = (Math.random() * (pane.width() - divsize)).toFixed();
var posy = (Math.random() * (pane.height() - divsize)).toFixed();
 
setInterval(function() {
    boxGreen.css({
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px',
        'display':'block'
    });
}, randomNumberAppearGreenBox);

 hit_div = $("#box").collision("#box-green");
  if (hit_div.length != 0) {
      alert("welcome Earthling!");
 }
```

```css
#pane {
    position:relative;
    width:300px; height:300px;
    border:2px solid red;
}
    
#box {
    position:absolute; top:140px; left:140px;
    width:20px; height:20px;          
    background-color:black;
}

#box-green{
    position:absolute;
    width:20px; height:20px; 
    display:none;
    background-color:green;
}

.score{
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.score span{
  display:inline-block;
 }

#score{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="pane">
    <div id="box"></div>
    <div id="box-green"></div>
</div>

<div class="score">
<span>Score:  </span><div id="score">0</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/andreighervan/pen/rPZgoZ

Comment: I used this hit_list = $(".menu").collision(".test");. but it say that collision is not a function

Comment: Are you **really** using jQuery 1.5? It's almost 8 years out of date. You need to upgrade it. Also note that the snippet has an error

Comment: My team leader told me to make the code in jsfiddle to send him

Comment: Did you include the Jquery Collision plugin from that link? http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/

Comment: I think I will use codepen and I will send him from there. Thank you!